# Does gethostbyaddr() function uses internet for converting IPAddress to Hostname?

Tags: c++, c, macos, network-programming

Does gethostbyaddr() function uses internet connection for converting ip address to hostname? Or it uses some cached data (like DNS cache)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It does a DNS lookup, which may be satisfied by the local resolver's cache or may not.

Comment: So if I call this function 1000 times in a row for the same remote IP Address it will get information from the cache without internet access. Right?
Is there any detailed info on that?

Comment: I want know next: So if I call this function 1000 times in a row for the same remote IP Address it will get information from the cache without internet access or not?

Comment: @sergio: There is no definite answer. There might or might not be a local cache. The name->IP mapping might or might not be marked as expiring soon. *Usually* the mapping will be cached, and you should generally avoid caching yourself unless you are prepared to respect the entry's TTL value.